# Issue with object not inheriting its prototype's methods

Tags: javascript, prototype

Check out the image. How can this be? Aren't objects supposed to inherit its prototype's methods?

King <-- FixedMovementPiece <-- Piece

Piece has the setXY method.

[image: Strange behavior]

Comment: `prototype != __proto__`

Comment: Please show us your code. Also, it is quite senseless to grey out your console output. Btw, to see the prototypes from which your `pieza` is inheriting you can click on the rectangle next to `King` to expand the properties.

Answer (score 2):

`__proto__` (defined in most current browsers but not in the current ECMAScript specification) is what gets used when the prototype chain is being searched through.

`prototype` is used when a function is called as a constructor, to assign the `__proto__` property of the new object. As prototypes are typically not constructors, `prototype.prototype` is rarely useful or even defined.

examples:

```
Array.prototype === (new Array()).__proto__ //true
(new Array()).prototype === undefined //true

var a = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', length:3}
a.toString() // "[object Object]"
var a = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', length:3, __proto__:Array.prototype}
a.toString() // "a,b,c"

var obj = {__proto__:{}}
obj.name // undefined
obj.__proto__.name = "someString"
obj.name // "someString"
obj.name2 = "anotherString"
obj.__proto__.name2 // undefined
```

Comment: Please note that `__proto__` is a non–standard Mozilla feature that is copied in a few other browsers. It should not be used for general scripting. Also, if the OP doesn't understand how prototype inheritance works, introducing `__proto__` is likely to confuse. It should only be mentioned in passing, if at all.

Comment: @RobG [`A __proto__ pseudo property has been included in §B.3.1 of the draft ECMAScript ed. 6 specification (note that the specification codifies what is already in implementations and what webites may currently rely on).`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), so it's good to be used. Thanks for letting me know that it's non-standard.

Comment: You misunderstand the the note. It doesn't mean what is already in **all** implementations, only some. [Ed. 6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=harmony%3Aspecification_drafts&cache=cache&media=harmony:working_draft_ecma-262_edition_6_11-22-12-nomarkup.pdf) (7.6MB) will not be a standard for many years yet. So no, it's not "good to be used" for general web development (as noted on the MDN page referenced). Also, the `__proto__` property will only be required for web browsers (if it remains when ed. 6 becomes a standard), it's optional for other implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Objects inherit from their **constructor's** prototype (i.e. the one the constructor had when the the instance was created), which is referenced by an internal `[[Prototype]]` property.

Only functions have a prototype property by default. e.g.

```
// Declare function
function Foo(name) [
    this.name = name;
}

// Add a showName method to its prototype
Foo.prototype.showName = function() {
    return this.name;
}

// Create an instance
var foo = new Foo('foo');

// Call inherited method
foo.showName(); // foo
```

There is also a **non standard** [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property in Mozilla browsers that references an object's `[[Prototype]]`, it may be in ES6 but it is not suitable for the general web.

Comment: BTW, is it defined what happens if you do `Function.prototype()`?

Comment: Yes. see [ECMA-262 15.3.4 Properties of the Function Prototype Object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4). You'll find it in the very first sentence.